# Getting multiband raster's min and max values with Python in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, statistics, multi-band

Is there anyway to have access to minimum and maximum pixel values from multi-band raster using Python in QGIS? This is QGIS and I loaded 3 different bands as rasters.

[image: Histogram Min and Max]

If there's a way to have access to them. How to do it?

`GetDefaultHistogram` gives different values for minimum and maximum. See below:

[image: Intel]

Is there a way to get the scale numbers from the histogram? For all bands?

Comment: By using **QgsRasterDataProvider** objects to calculate statistic through **QgsRasterBandStats** objects.

Comment: The colors: RED on band 1, GREEN on band 2, BLUE on band 3, are correct?? I mean they represent the colors of each band for the specific .tiff? Because in literature I have read in papers, I think band 3 = RED and band 4 = NIR. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6):

Next code works with multi band raster. It uses **QgsRasterDataProvider** objects to calculate statistic through **QgsRasterBandStats** objects.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

extent = layer.extent()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

for band in range(1, layer.bandCount() + 1):
    stats = provider.bandStatistics(band, QgsRasterBandStats.All, extent, 0)
    min = stats.minimumValue
    max = stats.maximumValue
    print 'min: {:.2f}, max: {:.2f}'.format(min, max)
```

After running the code with RGB raster of next image:

[image]

I got printed, at Python Console of QGIS, next values:

```
min: 62.00, max: 255.00
min: 89.00, max: 255.00
min: 90.00, max: 255.00
```

They are identical to reported in Metadata Layer Properties.

Comment: that is helpful, thanks! But still that is not quite the info I wanted. I want to get these values, if possible. (check the next answer)

Comment: @Berna I found this works, but it might not match what you see in histogram until you load the actual min/max range of values, e.g. in the raster layer properties. It looks like QGIS histogram dialog shows the **estimated** stats of your raster until you do this.