# Creating histogram for slope raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, statistics, histogram

I am looking at landslide distribution and I am wanting to look at the distribution of landslides on different slopes. Ideally, I am wanting to create a graph that displays the slope distribution for different landslide activity but also the slope distribution for the whole study region.

I know how to extract slope values for specific landslide points, however I'm confused as how I can use my slope raster to create a graph of slope distributions throughout the whole region.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Raster Properties Dialog](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html) documentation:

> To view and set the properties for a raster layer, double click on the layer name in the map legend, or right click on the layer name and choose Properties from the context menu. This will open the Raster Layer Properties dialog (see figure_raster_properties).

Click on the `Histogram` tab. See [Histogram Properties](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#histogram-properties) from the same documentation:

> The Histogram tab allows you to view the distribution of the bands or colors in your raster. The histogram is generated automatically when you open the Histogram tab. ... . With the Visibility option in the settings Prefs/Actions menu, you can display histograms of the individual bands. ... .

Take a look at this question to visualize how the histogram looks like:

[Getting multiband raster's min and max values with Python in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250070/getting-multiband-rasters-min-and-max-values-with-python-in-qgis)