# QGIS incorrectly says a raster's max value is 0

Tags: qgis, raster, debugging

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZzGojT96diSKEUdA7sB82m1Qt-FpDaRN/view?usp=drive_link) raster, 25.5mb uncompressed, 4.4kb compressed as 7z, has a min & max value both of 0:

[image: 0value]

[image: 0value2]

However R says it has a max of 1:

[image: R1]

And if I remove all the 0 values, there are 25 remaining values:

[image: R2]

[image: R3]

This feels like unacceptable failure on behalf of QGIS. Does anyone know what's going on, before I file a bug?

Comment: It sounds like the statistics are missing or corrupted. For speed QGIS only samples the raster if statistics are missing; the overwhelming majority of cells are 0 so it's quite likely that all the sampled cells are 0. This post might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256756/creating-histogram-for-slope-raster-in-qgis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the "Min/Max Value Settings" and switch to "Actual".

Comment: That solved it. What a huge time loss that was. Thanks for the input.